# Set state using onChange using hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get the `value` when I change it with `onChange` and created a name and contact number by using the `value` and `setContacts`, this app does not cause error but it does not work, Where is the problem? Thanks.

Each new contact in an object has an `id`, a `name` and a `phone number`

```
const AddUSer = () => {
  const {contacts, setcontacts}=useState([]);
  const { userName, setUSerName } = useState("");
  const { userPhone, setUserPhone } = useState("");
  const setName = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    return setUSerName(value);
  };
  const setPhone = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    return setUserPhone(value);
  };
  const handleNewcontact = () => {
    const allcontacts = [...contacts];
    const newContact = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      fullName: userName,
      phone: userPhone,
    };
      allcontacts.push(newContact);
      setcontacts(allcontacts);
      setUSerName("");
      setUserPhone("");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input className="form-control" onChange={(e) => setName} />
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input className="form-control" onChange={(e) => setPhone} />
        <button
          onClick={handleNewcontact}
          className="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-4"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddUSer;
```

Comment: You should do `[userName, setUsername]`, that's an array, not an object. Also, there is no need to return anything in `setPhone`.

Comment: @Chris Yes, thank you for my distraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the event to the function. You can either do

```
onChange={(e) => setName(e)}
onChange={(e) => setPhone(e)}
```

but better:

```
onChange={setName}
onChange={setPhone}
```

Comment: This is `onChange={setName}` how I write an error  setUSerName is not a function

Comment: This is how I write, I get this error, it does not work in the above way

Comment: It is a different error, you used { } in useState. change that to [ ] : ```const [userName, setUSerName ] = useState("");
  const [ userPhone, setUserPhone ] = useState("");```

Answer (score 0):

try this. the values are consoled when the user clicks the submit button.

```
const AddUSer = () => {

const [contact, setContact] = useState({id: '', userName:'', userPhone:''});

  function handleNewContact(event) {
    setContact({
      ...contact, id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });

  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(contact);
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form>

        <label>Name</label>
        <input className="form-control" name='userName' 
        onChange={handleNewContact} />

        <label>Phone</label>
        <input className="form-control" name='userPhone' 
         onChange={handleNewContact} />
        <button
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          className="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-4"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddUSer;
```